# Deteterminant of a zero-diagonal matrix with 1s and -1s

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider an $n$ by $n$ whose diagonal has all zero entries, everything over the diagonal is -1 and under the diagonal is 1. Is there a neat way to compute the determinant? Looks like it is either 0 or 1 depending whether $n$ is even or odd and could make it into an inductive proof but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: @ancientmathematician, no, how would it?

Comment: example $$
W = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr|rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  \hline 
-1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: $$
R = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr|rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\ \hline 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: $$
R^T W R = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr|rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: see Newman, Integral Matrices, especially the skew normal form, pages 56-59  in Chapter IV,   Congruence.  The comments above  illustrate induction, increasing $n$ by $2 \; \; \; $

Comment: @RobertBarg I was wrong in suggesting it was a duplicate. I have voted to re-open.